# How do you route to a specific controller endpoint if a url contains a specific substring?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I want to route everything that comes in with a url that contains "foo" anywhere in the URL to a specific controller/action.

How can I do that within a current configuration of

```
        app.UseEndpoints(opt =>
        {
            opt.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Have you read up on [routing in asp.net core?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0). There are many ways to do what you're doing, including routing attributes (see that page).

Comment: @gunr2171 I want to middleware this thing so I can route everything with a url that contains a certain substring to a specific controller/action. What's the simplest syntax within UseEndpoints? MapGet? Map? pattern?

Comment: I don' know why you need this but by creating a basecontroller you can override OnActionExecuting method. And you can be making routing in this method

Comment: @M.skr I don't want to make another controller and override OnActionExecuting, I want the simple syntax that can pop into UseEndpoints to cover this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use middleware,check the context.request.path,if it contains "foo",change path to what you want.Here is a working demo:

Startup.cs(put the middleware at the top of Configure method):

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("foo"))
                    {
                        context.Request.Path = "/Test2/TestUrl";
                    }
                    // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
                    await next();
                    // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
                });
                ...
            }
```

Test2Controller:

```
 public IActionResult TestUrl()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I was hoping some specific pattern would work in UseEndpoints but this works just as good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for your endpoints in startup class for every controller and actions:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "foo/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

and if you want to use for specific controller or action use this endpoint above default:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "foo",
                pattern: "foo/{ControllerName}/{ActionName}/{id?}");
```

Comment: This is very much not the answer